# how to insert data into tally using php?

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

i have fetch data from tally erp 9.0 using this code,

```
<?php
    $requestXML = '<ENVELOPE>'.
                           '<HEADER>'.
                           '<TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>'.
                           '</HEADER>'.
                           '<BODY>'.
                           '<EXPORTDATA>'.
                           '<REQUESTDESC>'.
                           '<REPORTNAME>Daybook</REPORTNAME>'.
                           '<STATICVARIABLES>'.
                           '<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>'.
                           '</STATICVARIABLES>'.
                           '</REQUESTDESC>'.
                           '</EXPORTDATA>'.
                           '</BODY>'.
                           '</ENVELOPE>';

 $server = 'LOCALHOST:9000';
 $headers = array( "Content-type: text/xml","Content-length:".strlen($requestXML) ,"Connection: close");

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXML);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);



if(curl_errno($ch)){
    print curl_error($ch);
    echo "  something went wrong..... try later";
}else{
echo " request accepted";
    print $data;
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

But my problem is how to push(insert) data into Tally ERP 9.0 using php(curl).

Comment: Can you answer the question here ? Im also facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

> $server = 'LOCALHOST:9000';

give

> $server = '10.0.0.155:9000';

Comment: Please, I need assistance: I want to use php to : (1) pull last purchased price from inventory.(2) select the company  i wanted to query. (3) Select all the stock items in the Inventory. I tried the above, but i got "request accepted Could not find Company '' . I will appreciate this

Answer (score 1):

use tally to generate xml format, and use same format to insert data back in to tally for eg.
to create sale voucher, get the xml from tally 
i.e

> GatewayOfTAlly-->Display-->Account Books--> Sales Register-->chhose
>   month-->ctl+E to export the voucher,

Now you got the xml format, you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$server = 'LOCALHOST:9000';
```

Use

```
$server = 'http://localhost:9000';
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
      <tr>
       <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <td><input name="nm" id="nm" type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><div align="center">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" />
          </label>
        </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    </form>
```

```
<?php
/* This is PHP code to insert an entry in Tally. All required XML tags by Tally are taken here in a string and name for Ledger is taken by posted value from HTML form. */


if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['nm'];
        $requestXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <ENVELOPE>
          <HEADER>
            <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
          </HEADER>
          <BODY>
            <IMPORTDATA>
              <REQUESTDESC>
                <REPORTNAME>Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
                <STATICVARIABLES>
                  <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>SAVH</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                </STATICVARIABLES>
              </REQUESTDESC>
              <REQUESTDATA>
                <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                  <VOUCHER REMOTEID="123" VCHTYPE="Receipt" VCHKEY="321" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Accounting Voucher View">
                    <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>    </OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                    <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>    </ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                    <AUDITENTRIES.LIST>    </AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                    <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
                      <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
                    </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
                    <DATE>20130401</DATE>
                    <GUID>f6c10ce3-4a15-42b8-961e-143a512a9e62-00000009</GUID>
                    <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Receipt</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
                    <VOUCHERNUMBER>5</VOUCHERNUMBER>
                    <PARTYLEDGERNAME>'.$name.'</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
                    <CSTFORMISSUETYPE/>
                    <CSTFORMRECVTYPE/>
                    <FBTPAYMENTTYPE>Default</FBTPAYMENTTYPE>
                    <PERSISTEDVIEW>Accounting Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
                    <VCHGSTCLASS/>
                    <DIFFACTUALQTY>No</DIFFACTUALQTY>
                    <AUDITED>No</AUDITED>
                    <FORJOBCOSTING>No</FORJOBCOSTING>
                    <ISOPTIONAL>No</ISOPTIONAL>
                    <EFFECTIVEDATE>20130401</EFFECTIVEDATE>
                    <ISFORJOBWORKIN>No</ISFORJOBWORKIN>
                    <ALLOWCONSUMPTION>No</ALLOWCONSUMPTION>
                    <USEFORINTEREST>No</USEFORINTEREST>
                    <USEFORGAINLOSS>No</USEFORGAINLOSS>
                    <USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>No</USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>
                    <USEFORCOMPOUND>No</USEFORCOMPOUND>
                    <ALTERID>20</ALTERID>
                    <EXCISEOPENING>No</EXCISEOPENING>
                    <USEFORFINALPRODUCTION>No</USEFORFINALPRODUCTION>
                    <ISCANCELLED>No</ISCANCELLED>
                    <HASCASHFLOW>Yes</HASCASHFLOW>
                    <ISPOSTDATED>No</ISPOSTDATED>
                    <USETRACKINGNUMBER>No</USETRACKINGNUMBER>
                    <ISINVOICE>No</ISINVOICE>
                    <MFGJOURNAL>No</MFGJOURNAL>
                    <HASDISCOUNTS>No</HASDISCOUNTS>
                    <ASPAYSLIP>No</ASPAYSLIP>
                    <ISCOSTCENTRE>No</ISCOSTCENTRE>
                    <ISSTXNONREALIZEDVCH>No</ISSTXNONREALIZEDVCH>
                    <ISEXCISEMANUFACTURERON>No</ISEXCISEMANUFACTURERON>
                    <ISBLANKCHEQUE>No</ISBLANKCHEQUE>
                    <ISDELETED>No</ISDELETED>
                    <ASORIGINAL>No</ASORIGINAL>
                    <VCHISFROMSYNC>No</VCHISFROMSYNC>
                    <MASTERID>9</MASTERID>
                    <VOUCHERKEY>177657027231784</VOUCHERKEY>
                    <INVOICEDELNOTES.LIST>    </INVOICEDELNOTES.LIST>
                    <INVOICEORDERLIST.LIST>    </INVOICEORDERLIST.LIST>
                    <INVOICEINDENTLIST.LIST>    </INVOICEINDENTLIST.LIST>
                    <ATTENDANCEENTRIES.LIST>    </ATTENDANCEENTRIES.LIST>
                    <ORIGINVOICEDETAILS.LIST>    </ORIGINVOICEDETAILS.LIST>
                    <INVOICEEXPORTLIST.LIST>    </INVOICEEXPORTLIST.LIST>
                    <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                      <AMOUNT>200000.00</AMOUNT>
                      <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
                        <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
                      </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
                      <LEDGERNAME>'.$name.'</LEDGERNAME>
                      <GSTCLASS/>
                      <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                      <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
                      <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
                      <ISPARTYLEDGER>Yes</ISPARTYLEDGER>
                      <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                      <BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST></BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST></BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST></INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
                      <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST></OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                      <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST></ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                      <AUDITENTRIES.LIST></AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                      <TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST></TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST></TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST></TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST></VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>
                      <COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST></COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                    </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                      <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
                        <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
                      </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
                      <LEDGERNAME>Bank of Maharashtra</LEDGERNAME>
                      <GSTCLASS/>
                      <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                      <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
                      <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
                      <ISPARTYLEDGER>Yes</ISPARTYLEDGER>
                      <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                      <AMOUNT>-200000.00</AMOUNT>
                      <BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                        <DATE>20130401</DATE>
                        <INSTRUMENTDATE>20130401</INSTRUMENTDATE>
                        <BANKBRANCHNAME>Warje</BANKBRANCHNAME>
                        <TRANSACTIONTYPE>Cheque/DD</TRANSACTIONTYPE>
                        <BANKNAME>AXIS</BANKNAME>
                        <PAYMENTFAVOURING>'.$name.'</PAYMENTFAVOURING>
                        <INSTRUMENTNUMBER>50026</INSTRUMENTNUMBER>
                        <UNIQUEREFERENCENUMBER>38ROUrdV00QEKOhl</UNIQUEREFERENCENUMBER>
                        <STATUS>No</STATUS>
                        <CHEQUEPRINTED>-1</CHEQUEPRINTED>
                        <AMOUNT>-200000.00</AMOUNT>
                      </BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST></BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST></INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
                      <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST></OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                      <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST></ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                      <AUDITENTRIES.LIST></AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
                      <TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST></TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST></TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST></TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                      <VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST> </VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>
                      <COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST> </COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                    </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    <ATTDRECORDS.LIST> </ATTDRECORDS.LIST>
                  </VOUCHER>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
                <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                  <COMPANY>
                    <REMOTECMPINFO.LIST MERGE="Yes">
                      <NAME>12</NAME>
                      <REMOTECMPNAME>SAVH</REMOTECMPNAME>
                      <REMOTECMPSTATE>Maharashtra</REMOTECMPSTATE>
                    </REMOTECMPINFO.LIST>
                    <REMOTECMPINFO.LIST MERGE="Yes">
                      <NAME>f6c10ce3-4a15-42b8-961e-143a512a9e62</NAME>
                      <REMOTECMPNAME>SAVH</REMOTECMPNAME>
                      <REMOTECMPSTATE>Maharashtra</REMOTECMPSTATE>
                    </REMOTECMPINFO.LIST>
                  </COMPANY>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
                <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                  <COMPANY>
                    <REMOTECMPINFO.LIST MERGE="Yes">
                      <NAME>12</NAME>
                      <REMOTECMPNAME>SAVH</REMOTECMPNAME>
                      <REMOTECMPSTATE>Maharashtra</REMOTECMPSTATE>
                    </REMOTECMPINFO.LIST>
                    <REMOTECMPINFO.LIST MERGE="Yes">
                      <NAME>f6c10ce3-4a15-42b8-961e-143a512a9e62</NAME>
                      <REMOTECMPNAME>SAVH</REMOTECMPNAME>
                      <REMOTECMPSTATE>Maharashtra</REMOTECMPSTATE>
                    </REMOTECMPINFO.LIST>
                  </COMPANY>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
              </REQUESTDATA>
            </IMPORTDATA>
          </BODY>
        </ENVELOPE>';

/* Actual code for importing goes here */
        $server = 'http://localhost:9000';
        $headers = array( "Content-type: text/xml" ,"Content-length: ".strlen($requestXML) ,"Connection: close" );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXML);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
            print curl_error($ch);
            echo "  something went wrong..... try later";
        }
        else
        {
            echo " request accepted";
            print $data;
            curl_close($ch);
        }
    }

?>
```

Try this, it will be working....
give your port in "$server" which is in tally configuration....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    

if(count($_POST)) {

    $group_name = strtoupper($_POST['group_name']);
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    /*$opening_balance = $_POST['opening_balance'];
    $opening_value = $_POST['opening_value'];
    $opening_rate = $opening_value * $opening_balance;*/

    $res_str =<<<XML
    <ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<IMPORTDATA>
<REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
</REQUESTDESC>
<REQUESTDATA>

<!-- Create Stock Group named "$group_name" -->
<TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
<STOCKGROUP NAME="{$group_name}" ACTION="Create">
<NAME.LIST>
<NAME>{$group_name}</NAME>
</NAME.LIST>
<PARENT/>
<ISADDABLE>Yes</ISADDABLE>
</STOCKGROUP>
</TALLYMESSAGE>

<!-- Create Stock Item named "$item_name" -->
<TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
<STOCKITEM NAME="{$item_name}" ACTION="Create">
<NAME.LIST>
<NAME>{$item_name}</NAME>
</NAME.LIST>
<PARENT>{$group_name}</PARENT>


<BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
<NAME>Primary Batch</NAME>
<BATCHNAME>Primary Batch</BATCHNAME>
<GODOWNNAME>Main Location</GODOWNNAME>
<MFDON>20190120</MFDON>
<OPENINGBALANCE>0.000 NOS</OPENINGBALANCE>
<OPENINGVALUE>0.000</OPENINGVALUE>
<OPENINGRATE>0.000/NOS</OPENINGRATE>
</BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
</STOCKITEM>
</TALLYMESSAGE>
</REQUESTDATA>
</IMPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
XML;

    //var_dump($res_str);die;

    $url = "http://localhost:8000/";

        //setting the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Following line is compulsary to add as it is:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                    "xmlRequest=" . $res_str);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            var_dump($data);
        } else {
            $msg = $data;
        }
        curl_close($ch);


}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Tally</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top:20px">
            <?php if(isset($msg) && $msg) :?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><?=$msg?></div>
            <?php endif;?>
             <div class="pull-left"><a href="export.php">Item List</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="pull-left"><a href="stockGroupItem.php">Create StockGroup Item</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</div>
               <div class="pull-left"><a href="ledger.php">Create Ledger</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</div>
            <hr>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="group-name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Stock Group name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="group-name" placeholder="Stock Group name" name="group_name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="item-name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Stock Item name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item-name" placeholder="Stock Item name" name="item_name" required>
                </div>
              </div>

             <!--  <div class="form-group">
                <label for="opening_balance" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Quantity</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opening_balance" placeholder="Item Quantity" name="opening_balance" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="opening_value" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Unit Price</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opening_value" placeholder="Item Unit Price" name="opening_value" required>
                </div>
              </div> -->


              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also please add some explanation to your code?