# How to conect php with tally?

Tags: php

I want to connect php with tally and I want to store ledger in tally with php any idea?

I got reference from different site like :

```
   1) http://www.tallysolutions.com/website/html/tallydeveloper/integration-capabilities.php
   2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717941/how-to-insert-data-into-tally-using-php
```

But it doesn't fulfill my requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, You need to put more details on your requirement, including what exactly are you looking for, what have you tried yet? your findings with code should be posted here. This way User can understand what's exactly issue you're facing, also attach appropriate tag with your question will reach to the right person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's may help you

```
// create a new XML document
            $doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

            $envelope = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('ENVELOPE'));
            //Header Section                
            $header = $envelope->appendChild($doc->createElement('HEADER'));

            $version = $header->appendChild($doc->createElement('VERSION','6.3'));
            $import = $header->appendChild($doc->createElement('TALLYREQUEST','Import'));
            $type = $header->appendChild($doc->createElement('TYPE','Data'));
            $id = $header->appendChild($doc->createElement('ID','All Masters'));
            //End Header Section

            //Body Section
            $body = $envelope->appendChild($doc->createElement('BODY'));

            $desc = $body->appendChild($doc->createElement('DESC'));
            $static_var = $desc->appendChild($doc->createElement('STATICVARIABLES'));
            $dup_combine = $static_var->appendChild($doc->createElement('IMPORTDUPS','@@DUPCOMBINE'));

            $data = $body->appendChild($doc->createElement('DATA'));
            $tally_msg = $data->appendChild($doc->createElement('TALLYMESSAGE'));

            //Ledger Data
            foreach($contacts_data as $key => $value){
                $ledger = $tally_msg->appendChild($doc->createElement('LEDGER'));
                $parent=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('PARENT',($value['contacts_types_id']=='1')?'Sundry Debtors':'Sundry Creditors'));
                $name=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('NAME',trim(str_replace( "&"," AND ",$value['name']))));
                $address=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('ADDRESS',trim(str_replace( "&"," AND ",$value['address']))));
                $state=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('STATENAME',trim(str_replace( "&"," AND ",$value['state_name']))));
                $pincode=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('PINCODE',$value['pincode']));

                /*$ledger_contact=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('LEDGERCONTACT',trim(str_replace( "&"," AND ",$value['contact_person']))));
                $phone=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('LEDGERPHONE',$value['phone']));
                $fax=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('LEDGERFAX',$value['fax']));
                $mobile_no=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('MOBILENO',$value['mobile_no']));
                $sales_tax_no=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('SALESTAXNO','23456789'));
                $pan_no=$ledger->appendChild($doc->createElement('PANNO','453456789'));*/

                $o['contacts_id'][]=$value['id'];
            } 
            //End Ledger and Body Section

            //Write the XML nodes
            $fp = fopen(public_path()."/xml/import_tally/ledger.xml","wb");
            if(fwrite($fp,$doc->saveXML())){
                $o['tally_rslt']= shell_exec("curl -X POST tally_server_ip:port --data @".public_path()."/xml/import_tally/ledger.xml");
                $o['modified_result']=strpos(preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $o['tally_rslt']),'exists');
            }
            fclose($fp);
            return $o;
```