# Connect PHP with Tally ERP 9 and Fetch Data

Tags: php

I want to connect PHP application with Tally ERP9, so as to fetch data from Tally.I need help on:

1. How to connect to a specific Company in tally erp9
2. How to fetch all the stock item in the inventory with the last purchased price per item. I will be grateful if I can find a solution to this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717941/how-to-insert-data-into-tally-using-php) is the link of what I got, but it throws an error of: "could not find company".

Comment: did you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to connect tally to have your connection in php. Means that first open your tally software and connect to your company with you credentials if entered. Then simple have to script executed. In my case http://localhost:9000/ is connection url which i use to retrieve data.

Comment: Do you mean I have to open the tally before connecting to it? Pls, the tally is on my local server, why the PHP is hosted in the cloud. How can i achieve this. Essentailly, I want to fetch the last purchase price of stock item, once the inputted part number matches any item in the inventory(stock)