# How to get Tally Prime data in PHP server

Tags: php, laravel, tally

Need to fetch tally data file in php server.How to do that in laravel.

I tried with CData connect server but it was not helpful.I want to fetch tally data file record in php server.
CData connect server URL :
https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/tally-connect-php.rst#Create-a-Virtual-MySQL-Database-for-Tally-Data_9ykr6hah3

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to get tally data from outside LAN,
as it involves exposing all tally data to world

If tally is running in same system as your php server then you can use curl to send request in XML

Refer this - [how to insert data into tally using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717941/how-to-insert-data-into-tally-using-php)
and for xmls use this [postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/13855108/TzeRpAMt)